# BeautifulSoup - removing MS Word specific tags?

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I have html document that was saved from MS Word and now it has some tags related with MS Word. I don't need too keep any backwards compatibility  with it, I just need to extract contents from that file. The problem is that word specific tags are not removed so easily.

I have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in invalid_tags:
            s = ""

            for c in tag.contents:
                if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                    c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
                s += unicode(c)

            tag.replaceWith(s)

    return soup
```

It removes not needed tags. But some are left even after using this method.
For example look at this:

```
<P class="MsoNormal"><SPAN style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold;">Some text - 
some content<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class="MsoNormal"><SPAN style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold;">some text2 - 
647894654<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class="MsoNormal"><SPAN style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold;">some text3 - 
some content blabla<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
```

This is how it look inside html document. When I use method like this:

```
invalid_tags = ['span']
stripped = strip_tags(html_file, invalid)
print stripped
```

It prints like this:

```
<p class="MsoNormal">Some text - 
some content&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</p>
<p class="MsoNormal">some text2 - 
647894654&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</p>
<p class="MsoNormal">some text3 - 
some content blabla&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</p>
```

As you can see for some reason `html` and `body` tags appeared there even though in html it does not exist. If I add `invalid_tags = ['span', 'o:p']`, it removes `<o:p></o:p>` tags, but if I add to remove html or body tags, it does not do anything and it is still kept there.

P.S. I can remove `html` tags there if I directly change where to look for finding tags. For example by adding this line in a method (before `findAll` is used) `soup = soup.body`. But still after this, `body` tags are kept hanging in those specific paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for t in invalid_tags:
        tag = soup.find_all(t)
        if tag:
            for item in tag:
                item.unwrap()
    return str(soup)
```

then you just need to strip html and body tag.

Comment: who can tell me why I can't see syntax highlight in my python code?

Comment: It does the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what's you purpose. when I execute strip_tags(html, ['span', 'o:p']) with your html, I can strip these tags.

Comment: Well maybe my question got out of hand. It should have been remove MS word specific tags with all additional generated ones. As you can see in example, for some reason body and html tags appeared and those do not disappear, I might need regex or something to strip from string directly.

Comment: _It prints like this:_
That might not be tag issue, that looks like encoding issue. Try to mention encoding ="utf-8"
it works in most cases.
However, if there are some XML lookalike MSWord tags, I also, do not know how to remove.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate Word tags, just save the Word document with the option Save As/"html - filtered".
Filtered leaves all the standard html tags intact but removes the Word formatting tags.
You can then do more tidying if necessary using BeautifulSoup.